# Largest number in k swaps

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, backtracking

Given a number K and string str of digits denoting a positive integer, build the largest number possible by performing swap operations on the digits of str at most K times.

Example 1:
Input:
K = 4
str = "1234567"
Output:
7654321
Explanation:
Three swaps can make the
input 1234567 to 7654321, swapping 1
with 7, 2 with 6 and finally 3 with 5

I am trying to solve it using two loops. For every index i, I am finding the largest integer between (i+1)th index to (N-1)th index, where N is the size of string. If the largest number is greater than arr[i], then swap it. Below is the code I have written.

```
public static String findMaximumNum(String str, int k) {
        int N = str.length();
        int[] arr = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            arr[i] = Integer.valueOf(str.charAt(i) + "");
        }
        int swaps = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++) {
            if(swaps == k)
                break;
            int maxIndex = findMaxInRange(arr, i + 1, N - 1);
            if (arr[i] < arr[maxIndex]) {
                swap(arr, i, maxIndex);
                swaps++;
            }
        }
        String out = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            out = out + arr[i] + "";
        }
        return out;
    }

    private static int findMaxInRange(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int maxIndex = i;
        for (int k = i; k <= j; k++) {
            if (arr[k] >= max) {
                max = arr[k];
                maxIndex = k;
            }
        }
        return maxIndex;
    }

    private static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
        System.out.println("swapping "+arr[i]+" and "+arr[j]+" from "+Arrays.toString(arr));
        int ch = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = ch;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(findMaximumNum("61892795431", 4));

    }
```

It is failing for few test cases. One of the test cases where it is failing is
Input:
4
61892795431

Its Correct output is:
99876215431

And MyCode's output is:
99876125431

I am not able to figure out how the output is '99876215431' and what is wrong in my approach. Please help me understand. Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Step it with a debugger and see?

Comment: This sounds like a great opportunity for you to spend some time learning [how to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your code.

Comment: It is not a coding issue, but an algorithm one. Your code follow the route `91892765431-99812765431-99872165431-9987612543` instead of `9186279795431-99862715431-998671615431-99876215431`. For example, here, as you have two `9` (max value), you have two select which element must swap with the first `9`.

Comment: If N and K are large you can optimize the approach by using a priority queue. Don't want to give away the whole answer but if done correctly, the time complexity can be reduced to O(N*log(K)).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. The problem comes from the parameter 4 (max number of swaps). If you use 10, the sorting is completed successfully.

Maybe the deeper problems comes from the fact that you are comparing the swaps of your algorithm with the swaps that you would do efficiently to sort the numbers. Your algorithm may work but probably it is not the most efficient, so the number of swaps needed is above the optimum.

Answer (score 0):

The basic steps how to solve this problem:
0. cast string to array of integers

1. make a loop K times
2. in this loop go from i+1 (LOOP VAR) to end of a collection and search for higher value
3. when we find higher value then collection[i], we will remember its value and index on witch it is. Important thing to note is that we want to swap biggest number but i also has to be last possible number.
4. at the end of iteration we swap the elements (i with best index)
5. we are done so all its left is convert our int list back to string.

code: (its python because java is pain)

```
def sort(swaps, string):
    l = list(map(int, list(string)))
    print(l)
    for i in range(swaps):
        best = l[i] + 1
        bestIndex = i
        for j in range(i+1, len(l)):
            if best <= l[j]:
                best = l[j]
                bestIndex = j
        print(i, bestIndex)
        l[i], l[bestIndex] = l[bestIndex], l[i]
    return "".join(map(str, l))

print(sort(4, "61892795431"))
```